# MongoDB nested grouping and separate array

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nested

I have this sample BSON document below, I am tring to find the total number of reports made by each traffic police and for each traffic police i want to list the `tpIdNum`, `tpName`, and the
total number of reports `makeReport` made.
I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "Name" : "Kevin Brown", ID: "KBB001"}, "Total Report" : 2},
{ "_id" : { "Name" : "Thomas Moore", ID: "TM001"}, "Total Report" : 1}
```

This is what I got so far but it keeps putting the `tpIdNum` and `tpName` together like this:

```
{ 
  "_id" : [ "KB001", "TM001" ],
  "Total" : [ 
    { "Name" : [ "Kevin Brown", "Thomas Moore" ], 
      "ID" : [ "KB001", "TM001" ], 
      "Total Reports" : 2 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

```js
db.trafficReport.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$TRAFFIC-POLICE.tpIdNum","Total":{$addToSet:{"Name": "$TRAFFIC-POLICE.tpName", "ID":"$TRAFFIC-POLICE.tpIdNum","Total Reports":{$size:"$TRAFFIC-POLICE.makeReport.reportId"}}}}})
```

```js
  db.trafficReport.insert({
"TRAFFIC-POLICE": [{
    "tpIdNum": "KB001",
    "tpName": "Kevin Brown",
    "makeReport": [{
        "reportId": "TO-001",
        "reportDate": "7-October-2021",
        "hasViolation": [
            { "violationId": "VID-001" }]
    },
    {
        "reportId": "TO-002",
        "reportDate": "12-November-2021",
        "hasViolation": [
            { "violationId": "VID-002" }]
    }
    ]
},
{
    "tpIdNum": "TM001",
    "tpName": "Thomas Moore",
    "makeReport": [{
        "reportId": "TO-003",
        "reportDate": "7-October-2021",
        "hasViolation": [
            { "violationId": "VID-002" }]
    }
    ]
}],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `TRAFFIC-POLICE` is an array, you need `$map` to format each item. `$group` would help if each policeman is a separate document.
So, if you want them in one document as they are:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Total: {
        $map: {
          input: "$TRAFFIC-POLICE",
          as: "pc",
          in: {
            _id: {ID: "$$pc.tpIdNum", Name: "$$pc.tpName"},
            "Total Report": {$size: "$$pc.makeReport"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - one document](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YqmMU529wQz)

Or, if you want separate documents, use `$unwind` before the `$group`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$TRAFFIC-POLICE"},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$TRAFFIC-POLICE.tpIdNum",
      Total: {
        $addToSet: {
          Name: "$TRAFFIC-POLICE.tpName",
          ID: "$TRAFFIC-POLICE.tpIdNum"
        }
      },
      "Total Reports": {
        $first: {$size: "$TRAFFIC-POLICE.makeReport"}
      }
    }
  },
  {$unset: "_id"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - separate documents](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4p6t_sO8VyX)